# Remove Spacings around each grid item?

Tags: grid-layouts

```
bar = VerticalGauge[#, {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", 
    GaugeStyle -> {Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.95]}, TicksStyle -> None,
     GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 50, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> None, 
    Epilog -> Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 15], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]]] &;

Grid[Map[bar, RandomInteger[{10, 90}, {4, 4}], {2}], Frame -> All, 
 Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

How can I remove the tiny space visible around each cell?  Using Spacings -> {0, 0} does not seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my first time using `VerticalGauge`, but I notice it's `Graphics`-based.

Add `ImagePadding -> 0` and `PlotRangePadding -> 0` as options to it and all the space will be gone.

As a downside, the grid cell contents will cover up the frame too.  You could use `Frame -> True` and `FrameTicks -> False` in VerticalGauge to work around this.

[image]

---

```
bar = VerticalGauge[#, {0, 100}, GaugeMarkers -> "ScaleRange", 
    GaugeStyle -> {Darker@Green, GrayLevel[0.95]}, TicksStyle -> None,
     GaugeFrameSize -> None, ScalePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 50, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, LabelStyle -> None, 
    Epilog -> Text[Style[#, FontSize -> 15], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]],
    ImagePadding -> 0, PlotRangePadding -> 0] &;

Grid[Map[bar, RandomInteger[{10, 90}, {4, 4}], {2}], Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Comment: Could you please post actual *Mathematica* code instead of an image? Let's encourage newer users by good example.

Comment: Your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: @RunnyKine The image was an afterthought.  I didn't post any code initially.  I think sometimes it's better to focus on the actual changes than re-post a large block of already available complex code which distracts from the point.